# In snowboard/ski cross, how are jerseys determined in the rounds?

Tags: rules, equipment, ranking, skiing, snowboarding

The first one is depending on the qualification times. That I know, but for the rounds after does it still depends on the qualifing time or is it determined by the position in the last round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the fIS rulebook at [article 2706](http://www.fis-ski.com/mm/Document/documentlibrary/Snowboard/04/36/62/SB_FIS_ICR13Snowboardincludingprecisionsfall13_clean_English.pdf) pairings for the finals will be according to the following:

[image: SBX_ranking]

So thi is the rank in the next round:

1. winner of heat#1
2. winner of heat#2
3. to 8. winner of other heat
   from 9th to 16th the secon for each heat

Each starting position is identified by colour and/or number.

Colours are determined by qualification ranking (time) in each heat:

- 1st ranked Qualification competitor – Red
- 2nd ranked Qualification competitor – Green
- 3rd ranked Qualification competitor – Blue
- 4th ranked Qualification competitor – Yellow
- (5th ranked Qualification competitor - White)
- (6th ranked Qualification competitor - Black)

Furthermore first ranked competitor from the qualifications can choose their lane, with the second fastest the next lane and so on

Comment: Ok thanks, that is how they are spread for the first round. My question asks for all the subsequent rounds.

Comment: @Fredy31 the answer is about the subsequent rounds after the qualification

Comment: Ok you edited. So someone that falls during qualifs will always have to pick last?

Comment: @Fredy31 this is another question, please open a new ticket on it